# Effective way to check diff for local and remote branch

Tags: git

Is there an effective way (preferred on git command) to check if e.g. the local `develop` equals `origin/develop`? Of course after `git fetch` was called.

Is `git diff develop..origin/develop` the correct way?

I'm not interested in the changed files. I only want the info "In sync - yes or no".

I want to use it in PowerShell so I would have something like:

```
$result = iex "git diff develop..origin/develop" 
if ($null -eq $result) {
    Write-Host "You're in sync"
}
```

Thx

Comment: `git status` usually shows if you're up to date with the configured origin branch; is that not what you want?

Comment: Is there a short form, that tells me: Ok, not ok, to use the result in a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git status` will show this information, but in a human-readable format that is subject to change at any time.

You can figure out whether the latest *commit* differs between your branch and the upstream branch by comparing the output of

```
git rev-parse origin/develop
git rev-parse develop
```

You can check if you have *staged but uncommitted* changes by running

```
git write-tree
```

and looking for the resulting hash in the first line of the output of

```
git cat-file -p HEAD
```

To check if you have *unstaged* changes, run

```
git status --porcelain
```

and check if the output is empty (in which case there are no unstaged changes).

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to use [`rev-parse`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse) to display the sha for each ref.

You could compare the output of `git rev-parse develop` and `git rev-parse origin/develop`.

For example:

```
git rev-parse master # 3526b45d70c56f607053ec8ea36ca6e1d7cc8a87
git rev-parse origin/master # 61fdef4fe9f83493c5e760c56809623c94c3c247

# master and origin/master are not equal
```

This would boil down the operation to a simple string comparison.